# Release Build does not build current source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I built the latest version using the Release build profile of VS2012 for presenting my application this morning. It didn't work as expected.

I presented a faulty application even though it worked fine this morning. After a few tests, I discovered that the Release build configuration caused the issue. I cleaned my project a few times with no change. I have this Button Event Handler in my code:

```
private void btnAddDatabaseValues_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");

    /*
    some other Code...
    */

}
```

In Debug mode, the message box pops up. In release mode, some other code is executing, and no message box pops up.

Any ideas?

I recently moved from VS2010 to VS2012 and installed Resharper. But I don't think this has anything to do with my problem since in Debug Mode all is fine?!

Comment: Did you have any errors in your code? Do you have "Launch Old Version" selected "when build or deployment errors occur?" Do you "Always Build" "when projects are out of date?"

Comment: No errors in the code, as Debug Build worked as expected and with all the latest changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean the solution and rebuild. The build is optimized to not run for projects that have already been built and sometimes this backfires.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the project is being build against the correct configuration, I've encountered a problem before where the solution was set to `Debug` and 1 of the projects had been changed to `Release`